# jquery mobile popup - better way to retrieve data?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm using this simple popup correctly initialized along with corresponding popupafterclose handler, wrapped appropriate in content div. It just works. -

```
<div id="start-activity-popup" data-role="popup">
    here is popup.
    <button id="start">Start</button>
    <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

But if I had to retrieve values from popup or know which button
was pressed - do I need to write another handler for each - start and cancel buttons ?
Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just write one handler:

```
$("#start-activity-popup button").click(function() {
    var clicked = this.id; //this is the id of the clicked button
    //do stuff
});
```